# How to get from JSON to Mutable Data

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I'm working on a Flutter "Collections" app where I want a user to be able to define a schema for their list, then create several items that conform to that schema.

```json
{
  "name": "My Book Collection",
  "schema": [
    {
      "id": "uuid-title",
      "type": "text",
      "name": "Title",
      "unique": true
    },
    {
      "id": "uuid-pages",
      "type": "number",
      "name": "Pages",
      "min": 0,
      "max": null,
      "format": "int"
    }
  ],
  "items": {
    "abc-123": {
      "uuid-title": "The Hobbit",
      "uuid-pages": 304
    },
    "def-456": {
      "uuid-title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
      "uuid-pages": 223
    }
  }
}
```

What strategies can I use to update Specific Items or Schema Items, preferable immutably? I'm thinking I can make a `Collection` which has a `List<SchemaItem>` and `Map<String, CollectionItem>`. I think I can use a Provider or ProxyProvider to provide the `List<SchemaItem>` and a "Selected" `CollectionItem` to downstream widgets.

What strategies to I use to update items:

- Is it enough to implement a `CollectionItem.copyWith()` function with some ChangeNotifier?
- Do I need to go higher, with a `Collection.updateItem(id: "abc-123", { "uuid-pages": 365 })` and wait for a Stream somewhere to provide an updated object?
- Do I jump all the way to the top with a Service? `CollectionService.selectedCollection.updateItem(id: "abc-123", { "uuid-pages": 365 })` and wait for a sqflite or Firebase update to trigger a rebuild?

I'm open to any starting points. All the tutorials, guides, and videos I've seen work with very simple data. Counters (Ints), ToDos (Strings & Bools), Pizza Toppings (List), but nothing with these nested maps. Do I just need to spend more time getting comfortable with OOP?

Finally, would I be crazy to work with the data **as maps** or should I definitely be converting them to Classes?

Answer (score 0):

just activate the robo pojo generator in your android studio and past this json schema and get the corresponding model class and use it as you want